# PDF watermarking

Tags: laravel, solidity, smartcontracts

I want to watermark a pdf in a document management system using the device's details.
When a particular user downloads a pdf document from a document management system, it comes with the user's details watermarked.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel if you have used dompdf then you can  achieve this via editing blade.php file  that you wish to have watermark

Or else you can use this package to override your pdf

[Watermarker](https://packagist.org/packages/binarystash/pdf-watermarker)

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. Can I put device IP address, Username as a watermark instead of an image?

Comment: @KanchanaM Yes you can

Comment: yeah , you can easily add image , text , ip address

Answer (score 0):

Set Watermark using DomPDF-In the first step follow this [url](https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/how-to-set-watermark-in-dompdf-laravel):

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).